Access C++ class pointer from Matlab
I have a program written in C++.  Within that program I would like to perform calculations on a car object.  The C++ program has an API where I can call getCar() returning the pointer to the instance. Is there a way in Matlab to receive the car pointer? The ways I’m trying to avoid are a Mex file and using the API to pass an array of the values I need.

A quick look at the matlab website suggests that you need to go through a "mex"-function, as that appears to be their interface between matlab and other languages. "Matlab EXtension, maybe"? I'd be surprised if there's a way around that.

We need more details. Your program, is it a library, a stand-alone executable, a cloud service? Does this API work through web sockets, or pipes, or …? What do you want to do with this pointer in MATLAB? You might be able to use it to call other functions in your API, but you won’t be able to cast it to a useful MATLAB type.

Been a while since I interfaced C++ and Matlab, but at the time Matlab didn't know C++ from a hole in the ground. You provided a C wrapper interfacing with the C++ code, wrapped that in Mex, and then  provided an m file to the user to make things easy. In general C++ objects are too abstract to pass around. You often can't pass them around to other C++ programs. To a program from another language, there is almost no chance that it will be able to interpret what's at the pointer.

Take a std::string, for example. There are three major implementations of string all with the same interface, but inside each one the members are different and those that happen to be the same are arranged differently. How the SSO buffer is handled differs radically, assuming that SSO is supported. You pass a std::string of one implementation by reference to a program compiled for a different implementation and if you're lucky the program instantly crashes. If you're unlucky... Happy debugging!

No way this will work

AFAIK, assuming you're using a current Matlab, the only ways of "connecting" C++ and Matlab are described via https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cpp-language.html.    You'll find significant constraints on any approach (just as there would be interfacing between any two languages - the more you depart from established rules associated with both languages and their toolsets, the more work there is as you have to deal with more excruciating low-level details)

You cannot mix native C/C++ memory (i.e., allocated with new, malloc, etc.) within MATLAB variables. All memory in MATLAB variables must be allocated with the MATLAB Memory Manager (e.g., mxCreateDoubleMatrix etc.). Trying to somehow get direct access to the Car object data with MATLAB variables can't be done. Forcing things (like setting a MATLAB variable data pointer to a C/C++ memory pointer) will result in assert failures and segmentation faults. You will have to deep copy the Car data into MATLAB variables if you want to work with this data at the MATLAB  level.
